# PYTHON file can run in IDE but shows error when runing in CMD or runing py file directly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below code work fine in JUPYTER NOTEBOOK or IDEs but it always show error while running directly from the .py file or cmd prompt.

I really need your help and hope you can advise me

My Code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd                 #install pandas, enter !pip install pandas if module not installed, Dataframe module
import numpy                        #install numpy, enter !pip install pandas if module not installed
import easygui


path = easygui.fileopenbox() #pop up box to choose the file
Document_Date=input("Please Key in Document Date: ")  #to enter the document date, only requried to enter once
Posting_Date=input("Please Key in Posting Date one month after document date: ") #To enter the posting date
#df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\chengwu\Desktop\Free travel\JUN20_Ridership.XLSX") #read the file you choose earlier on
df=pd.read_excel(path) #read the file you choose earlier on
df1=df.dropna() #remove empty lines
df=df1[["Company Code","Cost Center","Currency","Total Card Usage Cost",]] #drop unnecessary column
df.insert(1,"Document Date",Document_Date) #insert document date with values of document date inputed earlier on
df.insert(2,"Posting Date",Posting_Date) #insert posting date column with values of posting date keyed in earlier on. 
df.insert(3,"Posting Reference","Free Travel "+df["Document Date"]) #insert Posting reference
df.insert(4,"Document Header Text","Free Travel "+df["Document Date"]) #insert document header text with name = free travel +document date
df.insert(8,"Tax Code","P5") # insert tax code column and use P5
df.insert(9,"Text","Actual pass ridership fee for "+df["Document Date"]) #insert Text at last column
dr_copy=df.copy(deep=False) #copy a Credit leg , so far there is only Dr leg
cr=pd.DataFrame(dr_copy) #load Cr leg into pandas and name it cr
df.insert(5,"Posting Key","40") #insert posting key
df.insert(7,"GL","60100706") #insert GL
df.insert(10,"Cr","") #add a empty credit entry column (so far only )
df=df.rename(columns={"Total Card Usage Cost": "Dr"}) #rename original file to Dr
cr.insert(5,"Posting Key","50") #insert posting key to Cr leg
cr.insert(7,"GL","31000376")#insert GL to Cr leg
cr=cr.rename(columns={"Total Card Usage Cost": "Cr"}) #remane cost to Cr
cr["Cost Center"]="" #empty cost centre for cr leg (balance sheet 
cols=["Company Code","Document Date","Posting Date","Posting Reference","Document Header Text","Posting Key","Cost Center","GL","Currency","Cr","Tax Code","Text"] #define column sequence
cr=cr.groupby(by=["Company Code","Document Date","Posting Date","Posting Reference","Document Header Text","Posting Key","Cost Center","GL","Currency","Tax Code","Text"]).sum() #sum up cr leg by grouping using Co Code
cr.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True) #reset index
cr=cr.reindex(columns= cols) # re-arrange column using the preset column name
Group=pd.concat([df,cr],sort=False) #join dr and cr leg
Group.to_excel("entry.xlsx",index=False) #generate a xcel file for all entry
CoCode=Group['Company Code'].unique() #find unique CO Code and perform a loop to output into files 
for i in range(len(CoCode)) :
    Company=Group[Group['Company Code']==CoCode[i]]
    Company.to_csv(CoCode[i]+".txt",sep="\t",index=False,header=False)
    Company.to_excel(CoCode[i]+".xlsx",index=False)
input("press enter to continue: ")
```

And when run in CMD, the following error is shown

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chengwu\Desktop\Free travel\Free_travel_code.py", line 10, in <module>
    df=pd.read_excel(path) #read the file you choose earlier on
  File "C:\Users\chengwu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 208, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\chengwu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 310, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\chengwu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 819, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Users\chengwu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\chengwu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 359, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\chengwu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 36, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\chengwu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 148, in open_workbook
    bk = book.open_workbook_xls(
  File "C:\Users\chengwu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 92, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "C:\Users\chengwu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1278, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "C:\Users\chengwu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1272, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'import p'
```

Please kindly advise me what have I done wrong and if there is any way to change this.
Thanks alot

Comment: are you sure you have setup environments the same?   I also ensure that jupyter is run in same virtual env as my runtime .  From your stack trace you are using site packages - always a bad idea

Comment: how do i ensure that they are in the same environment